# Can i run a python script on my Raspberry PI through an Express Netbeans project?

Tags: python, express, raspberry-pi, apache2

Having an Express project in NetBeans, I would like to activate a Python script on my Raspberry-PI. Clicking a button in HTML should run the script and return the results.

Is there any way to do it? Using an Apache2 web server, how can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Will you be trying to access the PI behind the same firewall?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is your Raspberry Pi and your machine where you are running your Netbeans project connected to the same wifi on local network?

Comment: You can check my answer here if the answer is yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50100155/6198978

You can use the given example to extend your functionality.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Did you check the example?

Comment: Did you use a ssh pre-shared keys?

Comment: For ssh-ing you can use keys, for web server approach you don't need.

Comment: After I start working and keep you updated

Comment: I updated the question to simpler language (for international readers).